# Jquery: $.each() returns value then ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, resize

I have jQuery code to resize several Iframes based on the container they are in. When I did this without the `.each()` operator All of the iframes used the same div to base their size off of. With `.each()` the operator runs as evidenced by an alert but does not continue down the function.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bjackson2016/pen/oLQopy?editors=0010

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function resize() {
  var elements = $('.resize');
  var eachElement = $.makeArray(elements);
  alert(eachElement);
  $.each(eachElement, function(index, value) {
    alert(index + " " + value);
    var multi = value.data('wfactor');
    alert(multi);
    var ratio = value.data('ratio');
    alert(ratio);
    var minX = value.data('minw');
    alert(minX);
    var minY = value.data('minh');
    alert(minY);
    var ruler = value.siblings('.widthTest');
    alert(ruler);
    var pWidth = ruler.width();
    alert(pWidth);
    var adjWidth = pWidth * multi;
    alert(adjWidth);
    var eHeight = (Math.round(ratio * adjWidth));
    alert(eHeight);
    var unadjHeight = Math.round(ratio * pWidth);
    alert(unadjHeight);
    var eWidth = (Math.round(adjWidth));
    alert(eWidth);
    if (eHeight < minY) {
      $(this).height(minY);
      alert('changed height');
    } else {
      value.height(eHeight);
      alert('normal height');
    }
    if (eWidth < minX) {
      value.css('width', pWidth).css('height', unadjHeight);
      alert('changed width');
    } else {
      value.width(eWidth);
      alert('kept width');
    }
  });
}

resize();

$(window).resize(function() {
  resize();
});

});
```

Comment: You know you can just do `$('.resize').each(function(index, element) {...` right?

Comment: no. I did not know that. How would I call it when the page loads? would I have to have the same function written out twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no `value.data()`.

`data()` is a jQuery function, and iterating with `$.each` unwraps the elements, so you're trying to call `data()` on a native DOM node

```
$.each(eachElement, function(index, value) {

    // value is not a jQuery object here, you'd have to do

    var elem = $(value); // where you wrap it again.

});
```

Try instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', resize).trigger('resize');

    function resize() {
        $('.resize').each(function(index, element) {
        var elem = $(element);

        var multi = elem.data('wfactor'),
            ratio = elem.data('ratio'),

            ... etc

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: $.each() is changing or ignoring the hierarchy of the DOM elements?

Comment: okay... so the "value" variable was never a Jquery element but by using $(value) I can make it one and then it will work?

Comment: Well, no, `$.each` does not care about hierarchy, it iterates over the array you've created in order, the question is why on earth you would create an array to use `$.each(elements)` when you can you use the more appropriate `$(element).each()` instead? And yes, iterating unwraps the element, regardless of using `$.each` or `$().each()`, and wrapping it again solves the issue where you don't get the data.

Comment: Thanks! one more question. What is the second resize in ".on('resize',resize)" doing if ".trigger('resize is calling the function');"? is that referring to elements with .resize as a class? If so why is it not formatted "'.resize'"?

Comment: The second argument is the function, which you also named `resize`, hence a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks. That was a definite oversight!